# How to install alternate.txt for vim plugin

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

**Solved**
Thanks to @Gabe Moothart
I hit `:h alternate`  and got what I want

I am new to vim and I want to config it to become a c++ IDE.
I want to be able to switch between source file and header file. By looking from the web, I found a.vim and alternative.txt from [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=31).

I am now able to make a.vim works but how to install the alternative.txt is a problem to me.
Following is what I have done so far.

I have files:

- ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim, from [here](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/blob/master/autoload/pathogen.vim)
- ~/.vim/bundle
- ~/.vim/doc/alternate.txt
- ~/.vim/doc/tags
- ~/.vim/plugin/a.vim
- ~/.vimrc

I can do `:A` after I started vim.
I also did `:helptags ~/.vim/doc` and then `:h a.vim` but what I see is not the content of alternative.txt.


So, did I miss any steps?

Comment: what about `:h alternate` ?

Comment: Also, you mention pathogen but aren't using it. To use pathogen you'd want to put everything in bundle like `~/.vim/bundle/alternate/doc/...` and `~/.vim/bundle/alternate/plugin/...`

Comment: @GabeMoothart Thanks for suggestion